# clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '--param max-inline-insns-single=1000'

Tags: compiling

I am trying to install cosi2 downloaded from http://www.broadinstitute.org/mpg/cosi2. While running ./configure to install the program, I get the following error:

```
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '--param max-inline-insns-single=1000'
```

Following is the config.log generated:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by cosi_coalescent configure 2.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = n38-196.mtholyoke.edu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 14.4.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 257 tasks, 1297 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 3.86, Mach factor: 1.35
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/mhcuser/anaconda/bin
PATH: /Applications/Macaulay2-1.7/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/texbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2450: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2518: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2529: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2584: result: yes
configure:2735: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2774: result: build-aux/install-sh -c -d
configure:2781: checking for gawk
configure:2811: result: no
configure:2781: checking for mawk
configure:2811: result: no
configure:2781: checking for nawk
configure:2811: result: no
configure:2781: checking for awk
configure:2797: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2808: result: awk
configure:2819: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2841: result: yes
configure:2870: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2887: result: yes
configure:2966: checking how to create a pax tar archive
configure:2977: tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:3020: tardir=conftest.dir && eval tar --format=posix -chf - "$tardir" >conftest.tar
configure:3023: $? = 0
configure:3027: tar -xf - <conftest.tar
configure:3030: $? = 0
configure:3032: cat conftest.dir/file
GrepMe
configure:3035: $? = 0
configure:3048: result: gnutar
configure:3113: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3141: result: GNU
configure:3212: checking for gcc
configure:3239: result: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics
configure:3468: checking for C compiler version
configure:3477: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics --version >&5
./configure: line 3479: ccache: command not found
configure:3488: $? = 127
configure:3477: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics -v >&5
./configure: line 3479: ccache: command not found
configure:3488: $? = 127
configure:3477: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics -V >&5
./configure: line 3479: ccache: command not found
configure:3488: $? = 127
configure:3477: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3479: ccache: command not found
configure:3488: $? = 127
configure:3508: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3530: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3532: ccache: command not found
configure:3534: $? = 127
configure:3572: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "cosi_coalescent"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "cosi_coalescent"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "cosi_coalescent 2.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ilya_shl@alum.mit.edu"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "cosi_coalescent"
| #define VERSION "2.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3577: error: in `/Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0':
configure:3579: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC='ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics'
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
am_cv_prog_tar_pax=gnutar

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0/build-aux/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0/build-aux/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0/build-aux/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0/build-aux/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='awk'
CC='ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX11_CXXFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DEVOPTS_FALSE=''
DEVOPTS_TRUE=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GITSTATE_FALSE=''
GITSTATE_TRUE=''
GMOCK_DIR=''
GREP=''
GTEST_DIR=''
HAVELIBSEQUENCE_FALSE=''
HAVELIBSEQUENCE_TRUE=''
HAVEROOT_FALSE=''
HAVEROOT_TRUE=''
HAVE_CMPDIST_FALSE=''
HAVE_CMPDIST_TRUE=''
HAVE_GTEST_FALSE=''
HAVE_GTEST_TRUE=''
HAVE_PYTHON_FALSE=''
HAVE_PYTHON_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBSEQUENCE_INC_DIR=''
LIBSEQUENCE_LIB_DIR=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0/build-aux/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='build-aux/install-sh -c -d'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='cosi_coalescent'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='ilya_shl@alum.mit.edu'
PACKAGE_NAME='cosi_coalescent'
PACKAGE_STRING='cosi_coalescent 2.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='cosi_coalescent'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PYTHON_BIN=''
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=''
PYTHON_LIB=''
RANLIB=''
ROOTAUXCFLAGS=''
ROOTAUXLIBS=''
ROOTCFLAGS=''
ROOTCINT=''
ROOTCONF=''
ROOTETCDIR=''
ROOTEXEC=''
ROOTGLIBS=''
ROOTINCDIR=''
ROOTLIBDIR=''
ROOTLIBS=''
ROOTRPATH=''
ROOTSOVERSION=''
ROOTVERSION=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION='2.0'
WARNFLAGS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='tar --format=posix -chf - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='tar -xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /Users/mhcuser/Desktop/cosi-2.0/build-aux/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "cosi_coalescent"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "cosi_coalescent"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "cosi_coalescent 2.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ilya_shl@alum.mit.edu"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "cosi_coalescent"
#define VERSION "2.0"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Do you know whether you have both `ccache` and `clang` installed on your system? There are a lot of `ccache: command not found` notes in the log.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration fails because the environment had `CC` set to something like

```
ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics
```

or possibly

```
CC=ccache clang
CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics
```

(though experience shows that people who start putting extra things in their `CC` environment variable tend to ignore `CFLAGS`).

To see this, read the `config.log` file:

```
configure:3141: result: GNU
configure:3212: checking for gcc
configure:3239: result: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics
configure:3468: checking for C compiler version
configure:3477: ccache clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics --version >&5
./configure: line 3479: ccache: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are missing `aclocal-1.15`. That is a `automake` package and the default installs a different version.

`sudo apt-get install automake`

Installs version `aclocal-1.4`, that's why you can't find `1.5` (In Ubuntu 14,15)

Use this script to install latest
https://github.com/gp187/nginx-builder/blob/master/fix/aclocal.sh